# Question about proof of $7^n-2^n$ is divisible by $5$ by mathematical induction

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, induction, divisibility

We know that $7^n-2^n$ is divisble by $5$ for all integers $n$. Now the thing about most induction proof problems, is that we are usually already given the formula and we just need to use induction. But in this case, if we did not know that $7^n-2^n$ is divisble by $5$ for all integers $n$, we would need to test a few numbers first and then suspect that, it might be true for all $n$ so we use induction to show it is true for all n. Now here is my question: if it turns out that there was in fact a very large n such that $7^n-2^n$ is NOT divisble by $5$, would there be a problem with our induction step?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: See [why are induction proofs so challenging for students?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/why-are-induction-proofs-so-challenging-for-students) for more on what induction is.

Comment: If there is some $N>1000$ such that $5\nmid 7^N-5^N$, then whatever argument you may devise in an attempt to prove that, say, for all $n\ge2$ either $7^n-5^n$ isn't a multiple of $5$ or $7^{n+1}-2^{n+1}$ is a multiple of $5$ is bound to fail for $n$ equal to some $m\le N-1$, and therefore you won't be able to prove the statement $$\forall n\ge2,(5\mid 7^n-2^n\Rightarrow 5\mid 7^{n+1}-2^{n+1} )$$

Comment: Call the divisibility claim $P_n$. If it failed for some $n$ then the would be a least $n = k$ where it fails. $k\ge 1$ since the base case $k=0$ is true. Thus $P_{k-1}$ is true and $P_k\,$ is false, so $\,P_{n}\Rightarrow P_{n+1}$ is false for $\,n=k-1,\,$ contra the proof of the inductive step.

Comment: I wonder if you are confusing the rigorous method of mathematical induction with the heuristic method of empirical induction (guessing a pattern by looking at examples).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the base case for $n = 1$ is true. Now, it can be proven that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ for any natural number $k$. Suppose that the statement holds for $k = 1$: then $k = 2$ must be true. If $P(2)$ is true (which depends on $P(1)$ being true, which is true in this case), then $P(3)$ is true. And so this continues: $P(k)$ being true depends on $P(k-1)$ being true, which depends on $P(k-2)$ being true, and eventually we can trace this logic back to $P(1)$ being true.

Thus if there were in fact a very large $n$ where this statement was not true, then we would not have been able to prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ for *any* natural number $k$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true for all non-negative integers.

First of all the induction proof:-

Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that $7^{n}-2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$.

For $n=1$ it is true.

Assume it is true for $n=m$.

So $7^{m}-2^{m}=5k$

for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then for $n=m+1$ we have:-

$7^{m+1}-2^{m+1} = 7^{m}.7 - 2^{m}.2 = 7.(5k+2^{m})-2.2^{m}=35k+2^{m}(7-2)=35k+5.2^{m}$

Hence RHS is divisible by $5$ as $35k$ and $5.2^{m}$ is divisible by $5$.

Now for the direct proof.

You have $7=5+2$.

Then you have $(5+2)^{n}-2^{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}5^{r}2^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}-2^{n}=2^{n}+\sum_{r=1}^{n}5^{r}2^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}-2^{n} =\sum_{r=1}^{n}5^{r}2^{n-r}\binom{n}{r} $.

As you see in $\sum_{r=1}^{n}5^{r}2^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}$ , all the terms in the sequence have the power of $5$ atleast $1$ . So it is divisible by $5$.

So such a large positive $n$ cannot exist for which this does not hold . This can be derived directly without induction.

Now as to your question to why induction works, you should see the Peano's axioms. They provide the explanation for this domino effect , that if it works for successive elements then it works for all of them.